# Write an algorithm accepts a positive integer n as input, when executed, prints out a list of all self-aware arrays of length n

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Self-Aware Arrays.

> An integer array int[] A is self-aware if for each i < A.length, A[i] is the exact number of occurrences of i in A.

For example, `[2, 0, 2, 0]` is self-aware.

Write an algorithm accepts  a positive integer n as input, when executed, prints out a list of all self-aware arrays of that length.

Here are some Self-aware arrays have been found. But I haven't found an algorithm.

```
N = 4
{2, 0, 2, 0}
{1, 2, 1, 0}

N = 5
{2, 1, 2, 0, 0}

N = 6
None

N = 7
{3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}

N = 8
{4, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0} 

N = 9
{5, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}

N = 10
{6, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}

N = 11
{7, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}

N = a
{ a-4, 2, 1, <a-7 0s>, 1, 0, 0, 0 }
```

Seems we have the properties

[sum(A[i]) = n = sum(i * A[i])](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uIup.png)

[A[0] = sum( (i-1) * A[i] ) i>=2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvntD.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: See Self-descriptive number for a reference. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-descriptive_number

Answer (score 0):

**Outer loop**: Generate all candidates of length `n`.  This can be done with any convenient set product software; you need `n` elements in the range 0:n-1. For each candidate, filter and check (below).

**Filter**:

- The sum of the candidates elements must equal `n`.  Note that if you're writing your own candidate generator, you can use this to *greatly* reduce the quantity of candidates.
- The first element can never be 0.

**Check**:
Count the quantity of each number 0:n-1 in order.  The resulting list is your check count.  If this list is equal to the original candidate, you have a solution: print it.

**Shortcuts:**
Are you allowed to use known results?  It's long proved that for n >= 7, the formula you give is the only solution: you can directly generate the one solution and return.  For n < 7, brute force will produce all valid solutions quite quickly.

Comment: How can we prove  for n >= 7, the formul is the only solution ?

Comment: The first place I saw it proved was, I think, in Hofstadter's "MetaMagical Themas" column in Scientific American.  I've seen it in other places.  You can either research the known solutions, or work through the combinatorics.  There are some early restrictions that make it easier: the sum of the array must be `n`, and the first element cannot be `0`.  Once you get up to 7 and 8, I recall that there's an inductive proof for the others.

Answer (score 0):

```
function valueCountMap(arr) {
    let obj = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let temp = arr[i];
        let val = obj[temp];
        if (val) {
            obj[temp] += 1;
        } else {
            obj[temp] = 1;
        }

    }
    return obj;
}


function isSelfAware(arr) {
    let map = valueCountMap(arr);

    for (const key in map) {
        if (map.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const found = map[key]; 
            if (arr[key] !== found) {
                return false;
            }
            
        }
    }

    return true;
}

let arr1 = [7, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0];
console.log(isSelfAware(arr1));
```